# Hosting and scaling mongodb

Tags: mongodb, hosting, scale, scaling, database

I'm looking for a hosting service to host my mongodb database, such as MongoLab-MongoHQ-Heroku-AWS EBS, etc.
What I need is to find one of this services (or another) that provides auto-scaling my storage size.
Is there a way (service) to auto-scale mongodb? How?

Answer (score 1):

There are many [hosting providers for MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.com/partners/cloud) that provide scaling solutions.

Storage size is only one dimension to scaling; there are other resources to monitor like memory, CPU, and I/O throughput.

There are several different approaches you can use to scale your MongoDB storage size:

#### 1) Deploy a MongoDB [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-members/) and scale vertically

The minimum footprint you would need is two data bearing nodes (a primary and a secondary) plus a third node which is either another data node (secondary) or a voting-only node without data (arbiter).

As your storage needs change, you can adjust the storage on your secondaries by temporarily stopping the `mongod` service and doing the O/S changes to adjust storage provisioning on your `dbpath`.  After you adjust each secondary, you would restart `mongod` and allow that secondary to [catch up on replication sync](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replication) before changing the next secondary.  Lastly, you would step down and upgrade the primary.

#### 2) Deploy a MongoDB [sharded cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/) and scale horizontally.

A sharded cluster allows you to partition databases across a number of *shards*, which are typically backed by replica sets (although technically a shard can be a standalone `mongod`).  In this case you can add (or remove) shards based on your requirements. Changing the number of shards can have a notable performance impact due to [chunk migration across shards](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-migration/), so this isn't something you'd do too reactively (i.e. far more likely on a daily or weekly basis rather than hourly).

#### 3) Let a hosted database-as-a-service provider take care of the details for you :)

Replica sets and sharding are the basic building blocks, but hosted providers can often take care of the details for you.  Armed with this terminology you should be able to approach hosting providers and ask them about available plan options and costing.